# Get temporary file name during uploading

Tags: php, file-upload, temporary-files

How can I get the temporary file name during uploading ? (the tmp_name parameter given after upload).
I tried to use [Session Upload Progress](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php), the progress works correctly but the tmp_name's field is always empty.

Comment: I'd suggest that you supply some of the code that is problematic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) with the [rfc1867 setting *`apc.rfc1867`*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.rfc1867) enabled for this.

This website explains [how to do it](http://www.phpriot.com/articles/php-ajax-file-uploads/3):

```
<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS" value="1234" />
        <!--                       ###################              -->
        <input type="file" name="myFile" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload file..." />
    </div>
</form>
```

> Note: The `APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS` form element must appear in the form before the file input.

It will give you the information you need:

```
print_r(apc_fetch("upload_$_POST[APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS]"));
                                 ###################

Array
(
    [total] => 1142543
    [current] => 1142543
    [rate] => 1828068.8
    [filename] => test
    [name] => file
    [temp_filename] => /tmp/php8F
    [cancel_upload] => 0
    [done] => 1
)
```